# Django Admin- Dynamic child ModelChoiceField queryset on parent ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

This question have been asked many times. I went through many of them, and still couldn't find what i am looking for.

I am trying to load child ModelChoiceField data on parent ModelChoiceField selection in Django-Admin only

My code is as follows:

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
name = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
city = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all(), required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Address
    fields = ['name', 'country', 'city']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'instance' in kwargs:
        address = kwargs['instance']
        self.base_fields['name'].initial = address.name
    country = self.get_country(*args, **kwargs)
    self.base_fields['city'].queryset = country.cities if country else City.objects.none()
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

but it's not working on `onChange` event.

Comment: what do you mean it is not working onchange event?  Do you mean when a country is selected the city list doesn't change?  You need to use ajax for that

Comment: Yes, city list should be reloaded when country is selected. how can i integrate AJAX in django admin ORM only?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I did for cars.  You can adapt it by replacing Car Make with country and Car Model with city

Within the form `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['car_make'].empty_label = 'Make'        
        self.fields['car_model'].empty_label = 'Model'
        initial = kwargs.get('initial', None)
        try: self.fields['car_model'].queryset = CarModel.objects.filter(car_make=initial['car_make'])
        except: self.fields['car_model'].queryset = CarModel.objects.none()
```

Ajax view

```
def load_models(request):
    car_make_id = request.GET.get('car_make')
    car_models = CarModel.objects.filter(car_make_id=car_make_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'leases/partials/car_model_dropdown_list_options.html', {'car_models': car_models})
```

Ajax url

```
path('ajax/load-models/', views.load_models, name="ajax_load_models"),
```

Javascript (using JQuery) in template

```
$("#id_car_make").change(function () {
    var url = $("#searchForm").attr("data-models-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
    var carMakeId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

    $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
        url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
        data: {
            'car_make': carMakeId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
        },
        success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
            $("#id_car_model").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
        }
    });

});
```